# Could not find file 'bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml'. - When publishing to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having problem publishing my project to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk via Visual Studio 2012.

I get the following output when publishing:

```
Commencing deployment for project Test
...building deployment package obj\Debug\Package\Test.zip...
...package build 'CopyPipelineFiles': error in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets' at (2660,5): Copying file bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml'.
...build of project archive failed, abandoning deployment
Commencing deployment for project Test
...building deployment package obj\Debug\Package\Archive...
...package build 'CopyPipelineFiles': error in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets' at (2660,5): Copying file bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml'.
...build of project archive failed, abandoning deployment
```

I removed `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml' and it's main core files from the nuget but I guess it is referenced from somewhere but I don't know where. Where can I find this reference and remove it, so the publis works. Thanks.

Comment: Did you succeed? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

try clearing out your bin folder manually and then rebuilding your project.